# Merge data.frame rows with common column values

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Could you please tell me how I could transform the data frame like this:

```
    tg  qr  loc a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3  c1  c2  c3
1   A   1   89  NA  NA  NA  1   2   3   1   2   3
2   A   1   61  1   2   3   NA  NA  NA  1   2   3
3   A   2   38  4   5   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4   B   1   40  4   5   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5   B   1   3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  4   5   6
```

into this:

```
    tg  qr  loc a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3  c1  c2  c3
1   A   1   15  1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
2   A   2   95  4   5   6   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   B   1   42  4   5   6   NA  NA  NA  4   5   6
```

The function should:

- merge all rows with same values in columns 'tg' AND 'qr' into one row
- while merging, replace all "NAs" with existing values - never in the opposite direction
- Often there will be cases, when a variable is present in both rows being merged, but its value will be always equal (then it doesn't matter from which row it would be taken)
- 'loc' column values differ, but are not relevant, the column could be even deleted

Code for these sample dataframes is:

```
df = rbind(c("A","1",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(NA,NA,NA),c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)),
           c("A","1",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(1,2,3),c(NA,NA,NA),c(1,2,3)),
           c("A","2",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(4,5,6),c(NA,NA,NA),c(NA,NA,NA)),
           c("B","1",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(4,5,6),c(NA,NA,NA),c(NA,NA,NA)),
           c("B","1",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(NA,NA,NA),c(NA,NA,NA),c(4,5,6)))
df = as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) = c("target","query","loc",c("a1","a2","a3"),c("b1","b2","b3"),c("c1","c2","c3"))

df2 = rbind(c("A","1",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3)),
            c("A","2",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(4,5,6),c(NA,NA,NA),c(NA,NA,NA)),
            c("B","1",floor(runif(1,1,100)),c(4,5,6),c(NA,NA,NA),c(4,5,6)))
df2 = as.data.frame(df2)
colnames(df2) = c("target","query","loc",c("a1","a2","a3"),c("b1","b2","b3"),c("c1","c2","c3"))
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: `merge(df,df2,by=c("target","query"))`?

Comment: @Metrics Not really. I do not have `df2`. I posted it as the sample output I'd like to obtain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `na.omit`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) na.omit(x)[1]), by = list(target, query)]
#   target query loc a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
#1:      A     1  21  1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
#2:      A     2  71  4  5  6 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#3:      B     1  25  4  5  6 NA NA NA  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt <- dt[,lapply(.SD, as.numeric), by = c("target","query")]
dt2 <- dt[,lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("target","query")]
dt2[is.na(dt2)] <- NA
```

dt2

```
> dt2
   target query loc a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
1:      A     1 2.0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2:      A     2 2.0  2  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3:      B     1 2.5  2  2  2 NA NA NA  2  2  2
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to match with what OP wants

Comment: Thanks for pointing to data tables. However, the output does not match with one I'm expacting. I guess it will be problematic, if some of my values are strings?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @eddi, I assumed "Often there will be cases, when a variable is present in both rows being merged, but its value will be always equal (then it doesn't matter from which row it would be taken)" meant I didn't need to worry about that. Apparently I misunderstood something.

Comment: @mjktfw, a combination of `unique`, `paste`, and `is.na` should do the trick. It would return character values though which you can convert back. It seems a little messy in my head though.